# How to create a vertical brace in an aligned optimisation problem?

Tags: math-mode, brackets

I am trying to create a vertical brace around particular constraints in an optimisation problem. A segment of my code is shown below

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\underset{x_{ij}}{\text{minimise}} \quad & 5x_{11}+3x_{12}\\&+7x_{21}+11x_{22}\\&+15x_{31}+29x_{32}\\
\textrm{such that} \quad & x_{22}+x_{12}+x_{22}\leq 9,\\
&x_{21}+x_{42}+x_{23}\leq 5,\\
&x_{33}+x_{43}+x_{34}\leq 11,\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
```

The brace is to convey what the three constraints represent. An example of this is shown below

[image]

Comment: I think you want the `cases` environment.

Comment: @campa Do you have any links that explain this? I'm unsure of this.

Comment: @campa Not exactly; I am not creating a piecewise function. Suppose that I have multiple contraints in my optimisation problem. If I wanted to specify that, for example, three of the contraints were "balance constraints", how could I code a vertical brace (formatted to the right) to include a description to explain this?

Comment: You might want to incluce a picture of what the output is supposed to be. At this point I can only guess what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @campa Sure, I have done this. Does this help to clarify things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'rcases' env.
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\smash[b]{\underset{x_{ij}}{\textnormal{minimise}}} \quad 
 &5x_{11}+3x_{12}   \\
 &+7x_{21}+11x_{22} \\
 &+15x_{31}+29x_{32}\\
\textnormal{such that}\quad
 &\begin{rcases}
    x_{22}+x_{12}+x_{22}\leq 9\,,\\
    x_{21}+x_{42}+x_{23}\leq 5\,,\\    
    x_{33}+x_{43}+x_{34}\leq 11\,.
  \end{rcases}
  \cdots
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```